# Transfer Speed Limited by Fileserver?

Tags: network-attached-storage, nic, server-message-block, file-server

We have a 4gbit teamed nic fileserver that hosts smb shares. 
The files it accesses are from an ISCI NAS drive which is 10gbit.

Will transfer speeds be limited by the file server? Or does the ISCI "pass through" at 10gbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will be limited by the 4Gbps team. Even more so as you are limited to 1Gbps per NIC (assuming you are using 4x1Gbps NICs). Your clients are connecting to your fileserver, not the iSCSI target, after all.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know if the file server ends up pointing the client to the isci.

Comment: That would be a vastly different configuration. It's possible, but not exactly common.